Parameterized queries in Filenet Java API
When I checked the Filenet content engine documentation, I saw that we can execute regular queries. However I couldn't find any information about parameterized queries. Is there any way to achieve parameterized query in Java and if not how can I prevent SQL injections in my queries?

Hello, maybe you could ask to the FileNet support team? It looks like in the Redbook Developing Applications with IBM FileNet P8 APIs  that SearchSQL class does not provide parametrization, but maybe there is another way.
